# XFCE: Switch windows in Unity-like way (Super+numberOfWindow)

Tags: window, xfce

Is there any way to navigate between opened windows in Windows\Unity style (by pressing Super+ shortcut)?

Comment: You can go to `Settings » Window Manager » Keyboard` and see if you can bind or rebind the functions available there.

Comment: I didn't see the 'numberOfWindow' part, The only way I can think of right now, is not a pretty or practical way. It would imply adding lots of work-spaces and opening 1 window on each (maximum of 12) Then rebind the switch to them from `Ctrl+F#` to `Super+#`

Answer (score 2):

This is not a perfect way to do it, but it works for me.

You need to get the package `wmctrl` from your package manager.

```
sudo apt-get install wmctrl
```

Now open the keyboard shortcuts dialog by navigating Start>>Settings>>Settings Manager>>Keyboard>>Application Shortcuts.

Click the "Add" button on the bottom left of the inner pane. Now for the command, type

```
sh -c 'wmctrl -a {win title} || {cmd}'
```

where `cmd` is the command you type to open the program and `win title` is the part of the programs window title that is specific to that program, such as "Mozilla Firefox" or "Skype".

Now you can assign that shortcut to any key you like, particularly the Unity key you were used to before.

Answer (score 2):

I've achieved this by installing the DockbarX dock/panel.
You can run DockbarX along with the standard XFCE ones, or install the DockbarX plugin so that you can add DockbarX to the XFCE panel. I'm not sure what the pros and cons are as I'm still test driving these.

I've setup DockbarX to be vertical on the left (just like in Unity). When you now open an application, its icon will appear. You can then right click it and pin it. Now you have basically the same setup as Unity.

In the XFCE window manager settings unbind the Super+1, Super+2, ... keys so as to allow DockbarX to have them available. Now you can press Super+1 for the top icon etc.

DockbarX has some additional features you might like.

Just do a Google search for : XFCE DockbarX and read some of the guides.

Answer (score 1):

Check my answer on askubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/a/274231/44099

Together with `xbindkeys`, it works like a charm. No need for Unity ;)